# PLSQL not executing consistently from Access ODBC call

Tags: ms-access, oracle12c

I have a Microsoft Access frontend database that interfaces with an Oracle backend.  I have a variety of PL/SQL procedures that get triggered through processes in the application and I have never had an issue like this.  This particular procedure does not seem to execute some of the DML statements in the procedure when the procedure is run through the app (the Access database interface); HOWEVER, when I run the same procedure from my SQL Developer environment it runs perfectly every time.  More specifically, it does not seem to execute some delete statements that I have in the procedure despite the fact that I have COMMIT after all of them.

Here are a few other details that may be making the difference:

1. The table that gets modified by the PL/SQL procedure initially gets data from a SQL Loader replace job that moves data from the client back to this staging table
2. This stage table has an auto increment primary key that is created from a before insert trigger on the table.  There does not seem to be any issue moving records back to this table with SQL Loader or any kind of integrity constraint failure.  This all happens in the application BEFORE the stored procedure is called.
3. This particular table is also linked through the ODBC connection in the Access database, as it is used by a bound form after the above procedure is run.  I have tested to see whether the form is just somehow not reflecting the data in the backend table, but it is correctly reflecting.

Again, if I run the process in the application I get the incorrect results.  Immediately after I do this I run the same exact procedure from my SQL Developer and it corrects it every time.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I finally figured this out.  The issue was a timing issue between SQL Loader moving the data back to the Oracle staging table and the PL/SQL procedure getting triggered in the application.  Since I have a trigger before insert on my stage table in this case, I could not use direct load (direct = true) in the bat file that kicks off my SQL Loader job.  As a result, the records take longer to move to the backend and in this case my PL/SQL procedure was getting triggered prior to all of the records getting moved to the staging table.  This explains the intermittent nature of the problem that was driving me nuts.  I solved it by making sure the record counts in my delimited file that SQL Loader was moving back matched the record count on my stage table before I triggered the procedure to run.  Lesson learned.